# Getting the Qt Creator test scanner to find all test classes in one project

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qt-creator

Our team uses Qt Creator. We have quite large projects, and for each project we have a test project with a test class for every production class. The main of the test project calls `QTest::qExec` for every test class. We run our tests by simply running the test project.

That works fine, but the output is limited to the console, looking like this:

```
********* Start testing of TestClass1 *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.10.1, Qt 5.10.1 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) debug build; by GCC 7.3.0)
PASS   : TestClass1::initTestCase()
PASS   : TestClass1::test1()
PASS   : TestClass1::test2()
PASS   : TestClass1::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 2 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted, 3ms
********* Finished testing of TestClass1*********
********* Start testing of TestClass2 *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.10.1, Qt 5.10.1 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) debug build; by GCC 7.3.0)
PASS   : TestClass2::initTestCase()
PASS   : TestClass2::test1()
PASS   : TestClass2::test2()
PASS   : TestClass2::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 2 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted, 3ms
********* Finished testing of TestClass2*********
```

I just discovered the integrated test gui and would really like to use it. However, I can't get the scanner (Tools->Tests->Rescan tests) to find all tests in a project. If I write this in the main it works fine for TestClass1:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    TestClass1 test;
    return QTest::qExec(&test, argc, argv);
}
```

However, if I try to add TestClass2 as below the scanner only recognizes TestClass2:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    TestClass1 test1;
    int ret = QTest::qExec(&test1, argc, argv);
    TestClass2 test2;
    int ret &= QTest::qExec(&test2, argc, argv);
    return ret;
}
```

It seem as if the scanner only finds the last class executed with `QTest::qExec`.

Any idea how I could get it to find all tests, without touching the existing test classes?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @sfarbac No, sorry, I had to abandon the idea